# how to remove this error in WordPress Trying to get property of non-object in

Tags: wordpress

hello I have a problem with my wordpress site.

this type of error this occurs when I personalize my site with the Appearance / personalization buttons
I deleted all the plugins except the cache one
I tried to reinstall colormag which is my theme
I have trashed all my posts and pages
I cleared the cache several times
I removed all the customize css
I deleted the theme
empty the cache
reinstall the theme
But the errors persist

```
Notice: Trying to get property 'post_status' of non-object in /home/u4/domains/pecheperle.be/public_html/clone/wp-admin/includes/template.php on line 2302

Notice: Trying to get property 'ID' of non-object in /home/u4/domains/pecheperle.be/public_html/clone/wp-admin/includes/template.php on line 2306

Notice: Trying to get property 'post_status' of non-object in /home/u4/domains/pecheperle.be/public_html/clone/wp-admin/includes/template.php on line 2310
```

Comment: Error is not in the cache nor in CSS.. that template on these specified lines is trying to get properties of `$SOMETHING->post_status`, which `$SOMETHING` is not an object.... Error is pretty clear.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how to fix this error?

Comment: If I do not see the actual code, I cannot help you further... No crystal ball around.. [How to ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Can you paste the relevant part of your code?

Comment: Thank you for your answers
But what part of code do you need? Because as a reminder, I deleted the plugins, the articles, the pages and I reinstalled the theme